# helm install "unknown flag: --output"

Tags: kubernetes-helm

`helm install myChart-0.0.1.tgz --output json` results in `Error: unknown flag: --output`

I use helm version `v2.14.3`. According to the docs https://helm.sh/docs/helm/#helm-install this should work. Other flags seem to work fine. E.g. `helm install myChart-0.0.1.tgz --namespace test-ns --set random.variable="debug" --name mychart`

The documentation also states the schema `helm install [CHART] [flags]`,
while its examples suggest the schema `helm install [flags] [CHART]` in my tests both seem to work but non accepts the output flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output flag was added with [commit a52d6de9e17fc4dda4928f0029362e9be075aa24](https://github.com/helm/helm/commit/a52d6de9e17fc4dda4928f0029362e9be075aa24#diff-d58dc360b38373bb61ded7dfa6ec4ccd) which is only present in the `release-2.15` branch. The documentation is generated from master, so it already has the option, but your version does not yet.

Answer (score 1):

Your current version doesn't support the `--output` flag, to use it upgrade your helm version to `v2.15.0`.

From: [V2.15.0 Changelog](https://github.com/helm/helm/releases/tag/v2.15.0)

```
Introduced --output to helm repo list, helm search, and helm install
```

Comment: The changelog reference adds value, though.